# What is the format of key value vs document db?

Tags: nosql, key-value, aws-documentdb

I am new to NOSQL and understand that there are 4 types:

1. Key value
2. Document
3. Columnar
4. Graph db

This question is regarding the key value and document types. I am trying to understand how the data in these formats look.

For example, the key value format is:

```
{
 "ID" : "001",
 "Name" : "John",
 "Grade" : "Senior",
 "Classes" : {
      "Class1" : "English"
      "Class2" : "Geometry" 
      "Class3" : "History"
   } 
}
```

How does the document format look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an overview of the different data models: https://youtu.be/q81TVuV5u28?t=1175

Think about the difference in database models using the dimensions of 1/data format and 2/access patterns. Both key-value and document models have similar data formats but have different access patterns (i.e., key-value vs. ad-hoc query and aggregations).